# Python logging across multiple modules

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7

I'm trying to add logging (to console rather than a file) to my a piece of code I've been working on for a while. Having read around a bit I have a pattern that I think should work, but I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong.

I have the following three files (simplified, obviously):

controller.py

```
import my_module    
import logging
from setup_log import configure_log

def main():
    logger = configure_log(logging.DEBUG, __name__)
    logger.info('Started logging')
    my_module.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

setup_log.py

```
import logging

def configure_log(level=None, name=None):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    chFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(filename)s - Line: %(lineno)d - %(message)s')
    console_handler.setFormatter(chFormatter)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    return logger
```

my_module.py

```
import logging

def main():    
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("Starting my_module")
    print "Something"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run them, only the first call to logging produces an output to console - 'Started logging'. The second call to logging - 'Starting my module' is just passed over.

What have I misunderstood/mangled?

Comment: Why are you configuring two separate loggers (`__main__` and `my_module`) in the first place if you want to configure them exactly the same way? Why not just use configure `getLogger()` once and use that everywhere?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules) it looks like you might get away with an even simpler setup like so:

> If your program consists of multiple modules, here’s an example of how
>   you could organize logging in it:

```
# myapp.py
import logging
import mylib

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='myapp.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('Started')
    mylib.do_something()
    logging.info('Finished')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# mylib.py
import logging

def do_something():
    logging.info('Doing something')
```

> If you run myapp.py, you should see this in myapp.log:

```
INFO:root:Started
INFO:root:Doing something
INFO:root:Finished
```

It looks like your call to `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` inside your module is creating a separate track (with a level of `NOTSET` but no parent relationship to result in a log entry)

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble getting my head round the docs. And to output to the console it looks like I just don't specify the filename parameter like: `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`

Comment: Once you've setup logging as above, you probably also want to log to the console. This is a very easy way to add an extra handler to all your loggers,

    
# add the console handler to the root logger, and hence to all logger instances.
    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))

Answer (score 3):

The actual bug can be seen by putting the line:

```
print '__name__', __name__
```

at the beginning of *both* your `main`s which yields:

```
$ python controller.py 
__name__ __main__
INFO - controller.py - Line: 8 - Started logging
__name__ my_module
Something
```

So you properly configured a logger called `__main__` but the logger named `my_module` isn't configured.

The deeper problem is that you have two `main` methods which is probably confusing you (it did me).

Comment: is there a recommended approach to the deeper problem?

Comment: baxx, the recommended approach is to not use two functions called `main`.